# Differences between toSource() and toString ()

Tags: javascript

I want to know if there is any difference between these two javascript function methods; `toSource ()` and `toString ()`.

Comment: `toSource`: This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toSource

Comment: One [is only supported by Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toSource#Browser_compatibility), the other is useful

Comment: Ok guys noted...